# Trying to get a GUI but nothing comes up, no GUI, and no errors on command window

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("WORD GAME")
def game():
    print("Hi window !")

heading_label1 = tk.Label(window, text="WANNA PLAY THE GAME ?? ....")
heading_label1.pack()
button1 = tk.Button(window, text="YES", command=lambda: game())
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(window, text="NO", command=exit())
button2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Nothing is being shown in the output neither any error nor window.

Comment: `commnad=game` and `command=exit` without `()`. But to close window it would be better `command=window.destroy`

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
button2 = tk.Button(window, text="NO", command=exit())
```

actually **runs** the exit command as you end `exit()` with parenthesis.

To assign a command to a button you just supply the name:

```
button2 = tk.Button(window, text="NO", command=exit)
```